# How to make multiple captions for a single figure

Tags: captions

I have a single figure which is a subplot exported as an eps from Matlab.  It is 2 graphs side by side.  I would like to have a caption for each, with each caption centered under each respective graph. 
As I understand it, I cannot use subfig, as I only have one figure.

Can you think of any way to accomplish this?

Apologies for no MWE.

Comment: you can use as many `\caption` as you like in a `figure` and position them (eg in minipages anywhere within the float)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!  So I could place a \caption inside a minipage, and have two of them side by side?  How would I center each of them relative to the portion of the single graphic to which it referred?

Comment: You can write on image using `tikz` or `overpic` etc. Add the cpations yourself.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}

\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{2plots}

\raggedright
\hspace*{.9cm}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{5cm}
\caption{some sort of plot}
\end{minipage}%
\hspace{1.2cm}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{5cm}
\caption{a different plot showing a different function}
\end{minipage}%

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That works well!  Thank you!!  One follow-up, if I may - I need to reduce the space between the minipage captions and the figure. Any thoughts on how to accomplish?